# How to write this query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate

I have this database:

```
| id | name  | email           | control_number | created    |   |   |   |   |          |
|:--:|-------|-----------------|----------------|------------|---|---|---|---|---|
| 1  | john  | john@gmail.com  | 1              | 14/09/2016 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 2  | carl  | carl@gmail.com  | 1              | 13/08/2016 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 3  | frank | frank@gmail.com | 2              | 12/08/2016 |   |   |   |   |   |
```

And i want to get the COUNT in the last 12 months by the control_number.

basicly is a COUNT where control_number = 1 but by month.

So if the query is done today, its september, it should start from september to October 2015 and display the count of records for each month.

Result should be:

```
09/2016 = 50
08/2016 = 35
07/2016 = 20
06/2016 = 50
05/2016 = 21
04/2016 = 33
03/2016 = 60
02/2016 = 36
01/2016 = 11
12/2015 = 0
11/2015 = 0
10/2015 = 0
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `created` column in your table?

Comment: it is a datetime value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  Getting the 0 values can be tricky.  Assuming that you have *some* data each month (even if not for "1"), th en you can do:

```
select extract(year_month from created) as yyyymm,
       sum(control_number = 1)
from t
where created >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 12 month)
group by extract(year_month from created)
order by yyyymm;
```

If you don't have at least one record for each month, then you'll need a `left join` and a table with one row per month.

Comment: are you sure? i just tried it and its giving me 0 on other tables,

It is working just perfect!!

Comment: Yes you were right, i do have data that is not "1".. and always have data. so this is good. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ym, 5, 2), '/', SUBSTRING(ym, 1, 4)) Month, Count from ( 
  select EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM created) ym, count(*) Count
  from mytable
  where EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM created) > (EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
  group by 1
  order by 1 desc) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select concat(month(created),'/',year(created)) as period, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
where control_number=1 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, created, now())=0
group by (month(created));
```